# Synchronize Menu buttons and their functionality with forms

Tags: .net, winforms, design-patterns

Let's suppose i have a winform with a ribbon menu.
In this ribbon there's some buttons like "New", "Save", "Delete", and so on...
The application can open forms within them there are typical controls for managing data, so we could create NEW book/video/laptop, SAVE book/video/laptop...
how would you keep synchronized buttons (UI) and above all what pattern would you use for use a single button to manage all NEW/SAVE/DELETE forms (read books/videos/laptops)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Chain of Responsibility pattern. 
Forms must implement interface(suppose, IChain) in order to accept ribbon menu object (whatever proxy object that might be - ribbon may examine it lately and create necessary menu items).
On forms creation (which is event or Observer pattern) ribbon sends its menu-proxy to IChain. IChain implementation decides how to fill it.

Benefit of chain - it allows to handle method by many receivers. You can have nested forms and in that case it's hard to determine all menu combinations ahead. Let forms decide what to output in menu - that's their headache and responsibility.

Comment: Thanks, Nikita. And what do you think about synchronize buttons from main form (that contains the Ribbon menu) and sub forms? I was thinking to use a state machine like and in base of what i'm pressing enablings (or disablings) respond through it. For example: in state "NEW" i'll have in my configuration that modify, and delete buttons will be disabled, while save and cancel will be enabled.

Comment: At first glance, well, if you have finite amount of possible states then suppose it's ok to use state machine or conditional table, Again let each subform determine state transitions in case of specific form has some deviation of common rules. In .NET for example all menu items in form can merge into main form ribbon automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface containing common methods and properties that you need to use from the shared toolbar.

Then implement those methods in your forms. For example if you have a `NewDocument` method in interface, each class can have its implementation of the method.

Then in your main form, create a property `ActiveForm` of type of your common interface to store a reference to your active form. Also if you are using multi form infrastructure which lets you know the active window, you can cast it to your common interface type.

Then in your main form, when you click a button, like new document button you can call `ActiveForm.NewDocument` which will run the implementation for the active form.